# Visual Basic Unicode Encoding Error: Some characters get incorrectly encoded

Tags: vb.net, encryption, unicode, character-encoding

So im creating a encrypted messaging program in Visual basic, heres the backstory. When a message is sent it is encoded into Base 64(after being encrypted and turned into a byte array), the Base 64 is then represented as a string using Unicode(none of the data is actually changed), some padding is added to distinguish message types, then string is sent to the other computer(i have checked and the sent data exactly matches the received data so theres no issue there). Once received the base64/Unicode string is turned back into a regular Unicode string(this data exactly matches the data sent, so no issue there), then the data is decrypted, this is when the problems start, it does decrypt successfully and displays, most of the time it works but sometimes if you send a specific sequence of characters the receiving end will display it differently(as in they will be in asian characters). Now for some examples:

This is the data after it has been encrypted, converted into base 64, and had padding added:

```
{/} C/1rcE9CwYDEnoaxNVT2Xme/pky6yDRGo3lcG12G/h8= {\}
```

This is the recived and re-encoded data:

```
{/} C/1rcE9CwYDEnoaxNVT2Xme/pky6yDRGo3lcG12G/h8= {\}
```

As you can see there is no errors, this is the encrypted data (encrypting the string "EncryptionTest"):

```
Encrypt: EncryptionTest with 0K2V4Y0/aXrnGpcVP1d2JEGKAZDWZWuffXA1Iv0gFbc= got ﴋ火䉏胁黄놆吵延뽧䲦좺䘴禣᭜虝῾
```

This is the received and decrypted data:

```
Decrypt: ﴋ火䉏胁黄놆吵延뽧䲦좺䘴禣᭜虝῾ with 0K2V4Y0/aXrnGpcVP1d2JEGKAZDWZWuffXA1Iv0gFbc= got EncryptionTest
```

It worked perfectly, however if i send the string "Wonderful" this is what happens:

```
Encrypt: Wonderful with 0K2V4Y0/aXrnGpcVP1d2JEGKAZDWZWuffXA1Iv0gFbc= got 폮斚䢹뱊袗櫮㓟翔ǔ劇辑頭뷳ﭤ�

Decrypt: 폮斚䢹뱊袗櫮㓟翔ǔ劇辑頭뷳ﭤ� with 0K2V4Y0/aXrnGpcVP1d2JEGKAZDWZWuffXA1Iv0gFbc= got Wonderf牏匢否喏幙‥
```

Something gone wrong, but if i remove the "l" at the end of "Wondeful":

```
Encrypt: Wonderfu with 0K2V4Y0/aXrnGpcVP1d2JEGKAZDWZWuffXA1Iv0gFbc= got 폮斚䢹뱊袗櫮㓟팾甎ᑁᗺ寑핕杷
Decrypt: 폮斚䢹뱊袗櫮㓟팾甎ᑁᗺ寑핕杷 with 0K2V4Y0/aXrnGpcVP1d2JEGKAZDWZWuffXA1Iv0gFbc= got Wonderfu
```

Once again it works fine. The error is occurring between decoding the message from base64 and displaying it, so that must mean the decrypting function is to blame, here is my encrypting and decrypting functions, please help.

```
    Function EncryptAESString(data As String, key As String)
    Dim keybytes() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(key)
    Dim ivbytes() = Convert.FromBase64String(HashString("TestIV2", "MDA5"))
    Dim encrypted() As Byte
    Using aesAlg As Aes = Aes.Create()
        aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros
        aesAlg.Key = keybytes
        aesAlg.IV = ivbytes
        Dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV)
        Using msEncrypt As New MemoryStream()
            Using csEncrypt As New CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                Using swEncrypt As New StreamWriter(csEncrypt, uni)
                    swEncrypt.Write(data)
                End Using
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    DebugPrint("Encrypt: " + data + " with " + key + " got " + uni.GetString(encrypted))
    Return uni.GetString(encrypted)
End Function

Function DecryptAESString(data As String, key As String)
    Dim databyte() As Byte = uni.GetBytes(data)
    Dim keybytes() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(key)
    Dim ivbytes() = Convert.FromBase64String(HashString("TestIV2", "MDA5"))
    Dim plaintext As String = Nothing
    Using aesAlg As Aes = Aes.Create()
        aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros
        aesAlg.Key = keybytes
        aesAlg.IV = ivbytes
        Dim decryptor As ICryptoTransform = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV)
        Using msDecrypt As New MemoryStream(databyte)
            Using csDecrypt As New CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                Using srDecrypt As New StreamReader(csDecrypt, uni)
                    plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    databyte = Nothing
    keybytes = Nothing
    ivbytes = Nothing
    DebugPrint("Decrypt: " + data + " with " + key + " got " + plaintext)
    Return plaintext
End Function
```

Comment: Never use Unicode to represent arbitrary binary data. If you want to print it for human consumption, encode it with Hex or Base64 to see what's going on.

Comment: uni.GetString() is a bug, *encrypted* is not utf-16 encoded text.  You have to convert to base64 sooner.

Comment: @ArtjomB. after the Encryption the data is encoded as base64.

Comment: @HansPassant what do you mean a bug? and i am aware of the difference between encrypted and encoded, and the dangers of storing data as a Unicode string.

Comment: @ArrowPulford No, it's not, but it should be.

Comment: The IV must be unpredictable (read: random). Don't use a static IV, because that makes the cipher deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. An attacker who observes ciphertexts can determine when the same message prefix was sent before. The IV is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Usually, it is simply prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off before decryption.

Comment: @ArtjomB the encoding into base64 is in a separate function, and is called onto the Encrypted data after the encrypting. also thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray()` outside of `Using csEncrypt` in order for the last block to be written. This basically means that you're currently producing the ciphertext bytes before the padding is applied and the last block of the plaintext is written.

```
Using msEncrypt As New MemoryStream()
    Using csEncrypt As New CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
        Using swEncrypt As New StreamWriter(csEncrypt, uni)
            swEncrypt.Write(data)
        End Using
    End Using
    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray()
End Using
```

Your other issue is that Strings are not a container for binary data. Some bytes might be lost. If you want to print strings, you need to use something like Hex or Base64.

During encryption, you should use `Return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted)` and during decryption, you need to use the opposite function `Dim databyte() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(data)`.

Comment: Thank you, i should of checked if the byte arrays matched before and after going through encryption and decryption. I thought some of the data was lost during all the encoding and decoding.

Comment: nvm, this does fix the majority of encoding screw ups however some specific strings will still cause the message to display incorrectly

Comment: What messages are those and how are they different from what you expect? Note that I extend my answer a bit.

Comment: ok, after counting the bytes before and after all the encoding and encrypting i have found that the strings are consistently missing 2 bytes. Im new to stack overflow so im not sure if this should be a new question. any help?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of code that demonstrates your issue? For example, ideone.com is a good place. I've created this snippet, but there it works without an issue: https://ideone.com/Oq0GH3

Comment: Getting my script to work in the context of a console application would take to long and would probably introduce different errors, so here is just a dump of my code, so far its not very long. https://ideone.com/Cs5T2t

Comment: Actually after restarting my computer i could no longer replicate the error? I can only assume that maybe visual studio is to blame or the vb.net compiler. however i am still reading that each message is consistently loosing 2 bytes, im sure this will cause some sort of problem in the future.

Comment: Ideone is not for dumping some non-runnable code. A [gist](https://gist.github.com/) is better in that regard. Anyway, as I cannot reproduce your issue, I can't help you further. What I can say, is that you really should choose a different padding like PKCS7.